# why the byte address stores only 2 digits in below example?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, endianness

```
int x = 0x76543210;
char *c = (char*) &x;

Big endian format:
------------------
Byte address  | 0x01 | 0x02 | 0x03 | 0x04 | 
              +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Byte content  | 0x76 | 0x54 | 0x32 | 0x10 |
```

why does the byte address ox01 stores only 0x76 not 0x765?

Comment: The `0x01` location supposed to be of one byte on your system and one byte memory location can store max value of `0xFF` if `x` is of  `unsigned ` type. Hence value `0x76` gets stored in `0x01` location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A byte is 8 bits, and in hex that goes from 0x00 --> 0xFF (0 -> 255).

0x765 - which is hex - cannot possibly fit in 8 bits.